# Errata in "Practical Reverse Engineering"?

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, reverse-engineering

I've just started the book *Practical Reverse Engineering* by Bruce Dang et alia, and am confused about a portion of the "walk-through" at the end of chapter one. This is the relevant portion of code:

```
65: ...
66: loc_10001d16:
67:     mov eax, [ebp-118h]
68:     mov ecx, [ebp-128h]
69:     jmp short loc_10001d2a (line 73)
70: loc_10001d24:
71:     mov eax, [ebp+0ch]
72:     mov ecx, [ebp+0ch]
73: loc_10001d2a:
74:     cmp eax, ecx
75:     pop esi
76:     jnz short loc_10001D38 (line 82)
77:     xor eax, eax
78:     pop edi
79:     mov esp, ebp
80:     pop ebp
81:     retn 0ch
82: ...
```

And the authors' commentary:

> "After the loop exits, execution resumes at line 66. Lines 67–68 save the matching `PROCESSENTRY32`’s `th32ParentProcessID/th32ProcessID` in `EAX/ECX` and
>   continue execution at 73. Notice that Line 66 is also a jump target in line 43.
>   Lines 70–74 read the `fdwReason` parameter of `DllMain` (`EBP+C`) and check
>   whether it is 0 (`DLL_PROCESS_DETACH`). If it is, the return value is set to 0 and
>   it returns; otherwise, it goes to line 82."

This is not how I interpreted the code when reading it; surely any jump to `loc_10001d24` (line 70) will cause the function to terminate with return value 0 *unconditionally*, and not only if the value at `ebp+0x0c` is 0? (I assume that `pop`ing into `esi` does not affect the `eflags` register, and that the jump in line 76 conditions on the result of `cmp eax, ecx` in line 74?) This is also consistent with earlier portions in the code, which jump to `loc_10001d24` if various called functions return with values indicating failure.

In addition, I thought the point of the section starting at line 66 was to also return with value 0 if `PROCESSENTRY32` (a structure defined earlier, starting at position `ebp-0x130` in memory) has equal `th32ParentProcessID` (`ebp-0x118` in memory) and `th32ProcessID` (`ebp-0x128` in memory) entries; is this correct? The authors' commentary did not seem to indicate this.

As a more general question, even just chapter 1 of the book has seemed to have had quite a large number of typos; does anyone know of a webpage collecting errata from the book anywhere?

Comment: @PeterCordes cool, ty; that's what I figured

Comment: You can find some of the Errata on the publisher's site, section Errata: https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Practical+Reverse+Engineering%3A+x86%2C+x64%2C+ARM%2C+Windows+Kernel%2C+Reversing+Tools%2C+and+Obfuscation-p-9781118787311

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, ECX and EAX are both loaded from the same memory location, so unless something else has a pointer to it and is changing it asynchronously, `cmp x,x` / `jne` will always be not-taken.  Unlike floating-point, ever possible integer is equal to itself.

And you're correct, `pop` doesn't change EFLAGS, as per Intel's manuals: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pop.

To check whether a memory location is zero, you can load it into a reg for `test eax,eax` / `jnz`
or `cmp dword ptr [ebp + 0xc], 0` / `jne`.

(JNE and JNZ are the same instruction; the different mnemonics let you express the semantic meanings of equality or directly being zero based on ZF being set according to the value itself.)

---

> Lines 70–74 read the fdwReason parameter of DllMain (EBP+C) and check whether it is 0 (DLL_PROCESS_DETACH)

This is bogus.  If the book is full of stuff like that, that doesn't sound like a good book.

The `cmp eax,ecx` only makes any sense when reached from the path that loaded 2 different values.  (And couldn't use `test` for that, `x & y != 0` doesn't tell you whether they were equal.)  This seems unlikely to be real compiler output.

Answer (score 3):

This is the full listing. It's part of malware found in the wild:

```
01:    ; BOOL __stdcall DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
02:                _DllMain@12 proc near                 
03: 55               push    ebp
04: 8B EC            mov     ebp, esp
05: 81 EC 30 01 00+  sub     esp, 130h
06: 57               push    edi
07: 0F 01 4D F8      sidt    fword ptr [ebp-8] 
08: 8B 45 FA         mov     eax, [ebp-6] 
09: 3D 00 F4 03 80   cmp     eax, 8003F400h 
10: 76 10            jbe     short loc_10001C88 (line 18) 
11: 3D 00 74 04 80   cmp     eax, 80047400h
12: 73 09            jnb     short loc_10001C88 (line 18) 
13: 33 C0            xor     eax, eax 
14: 5F               pop     edi 
15: 8B E5            mov     esp, ebp 
16: 5D               pop     ebp 
17: C2 0C 00         retn    0Ch 
18:                loc_10001C88:                         
19: 33 C0            xor     eax, eax 
20: B9 49 00 00 00   mov     ecx, 49h 
21: 8D BD D4 FE FF+  lea     edi, [ebp-12Ch] 
22: C7 85 D0 FE FF+  mov     dword ptr [ebp-130h], 0 
23: 50               push    eax
24: 6A 02            push    2
25: F3 AB            rep stosd 
26: E8 2D 2F 00 00   call    CreateToolhelp32Snapshot
27: 8B F8            mov     edi, eax 
28: 83 FF FF         cmp     edi, 0FFFFFFFFh
29: 75 09            jnz     short loc_10001CB9 (line 35)
30: 33 C0            xor     eax, eax
31: 5F               pop     edi
32: 8B E5            mov     esp, ebp
33: 5D               pop     ebp
34: C2 0C 00         retn    0Ch
35:                loc_10001CB9:
36: 8D 85 D0 FE FF+  lea     eax, [ebp-130h] 
37: 56               push    esi
38: 50               push    eax 
39: 57               push    edi
40: C7 85 D0 FE FF+  mov     dword ptr [ebp-130h], 128h 
41: E8 FF 2E 00 00   call    Process32First
42: 85 C0            test    eax, eax
43: 74 4F            jz      short loc_10001D24 (line 70)
44: 8B 35 C0 50 00+  mov     esi, ds:_stricmp
45: 8D 8D F4 FE FF+  lea     ecx, [ebp-10Ch] 
46: 68 50 7C 00 10   push    10007C50h
47: 51               push    ecx
48: FF D6            call    esi 
49: 83 C4 08         add     esp, 8
50: 85 C0            test    eax, eax
51: 74 26            jz      short loc_10001D16 (line 66)
52:                loc_10001CF0:
53: 8D 95 D0 FE FF+  lea     edx, [ebp-130h]
54: 52               push    edx
55: 57               push    edi 
56: E8 CD 2E 00 00   call    Process32Next
57: 85 C0            test    eax, eax
58: 74 23            jz      short loc_10001D24 (line 70)
59: 8D 85 F4 FE FF+  lea     eax, [ebp-10Ch] 
60: 68 50 7C 00 10   push    10007C50h
61: 50               push    eax 
62: FF D6            call    esi 
63: 83 C4 08         add     esp, 8
64: 85 C0            test    eax, eax
65: 75 DA            jnz     short loc_10001CF0 (line 52)
66:                loc_10001D16: 
67: 8B 85 E8 FE FF+  mov     eax, [ebp-118h] 
68: 8B 8D D8 FE FF+  mov     ecx, [ebp-128h] 
69: EB 06            jmp     short loc_10001D2A (line 73)
70:                loc_10001D24: 
71: 8B 45 0C         mov     eax, [ebp+0Ch] 
72: 8B 4D 0C         mov     ecx, [ebp+0Ch] 
73:                loc_10001D2A: 
74: 3B C1            cmp     eax, ecx
75: 5E               pop     esi
76: 75 09            jnz     short loc_10001D38 (line 82) 
77: 33 C0            xor     eax, eax
78: 5F               pop     edi
79: 8B E5            mov     esp, ebp
80: 5D               pop     ebp
81: C2 0C 00         retn    0Ch
82:                loc_10001D38: 
83: 8B 45 0C         mov     eax, [ebp+0Ch] 
84: 48               dec     eax
85: 75 15            jnz     short loc_10001D53 (line 93) 
86: 6A 00            push    0 
87: 6A 00            push    0 
88: 6A 00            push    0 
89: 68 D0 32 00 10   push    100032D0h 
90: 6A 00            push    0 
91: 6A 00            push    0 
92: FF 15 20 50 00+  call    ds:CreateThread
93:                loc_10001D53: 
94: B8 01 00 00 00   mov     eax, 1
95: 5F               pop     edi
96: 8B E5            mov     esp, ebp
97: 5D               pop     ebp
98: C2 0C 00         retn    0Ch
99:                _DllMain@12 endp
```

So lines 70-74 make no sense on their own, but do serve the original purpose - if either `Process32First()/Process32Next()` returns `FALSE` then the code jumps here and eventually exits with 0.
And if the desired process was found then eax/ecx are set to ParentProcessID/ProcessID respectively so the function will continue.

---

Anyway, there's also lines 83-85 which the books states:

*...with lpStartAddress as 0x100032D0. This block can be decompiled as follows:*

```
if (fdwReason == DLL_PROCESS_DETACH) { return FALSE; }
if (fdwReason == DLL_THREAD_ATTACH || fdwReason == DLL_THREAD_DETACH) { return TRUE; }
CreateThread(0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) 0x100032D0, 0, 0, 0);
return TRUE;
```

Lines 83-85 actually check if `fdwReason` equals `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH` or not (bypassing the call to `CreateThread` if not, which makes perfect sense), and there's no special case for `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH`.

I'll say that the book certainly lacks proper structure, some things the book takes for granted, other maybe mundane things are emphasizes. Still a very good resource.

Oh well, who said this was easy.

Comment: Hey @Assaf Levy, sorry for the late response on this! Haven't been on SO in a while. Thank you so much for detailed answer though, very helpful.